# Diferenciar un programa con un HASH en QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola quiero crear un alias a cada programa que creo en qt y que este alias sea diferente. Estaba pensando en usar hashes y convertilo en un string. Por ejemplo:
Yo compilo un programa cada vez que compilo ese programa tiene que tener un ALIAS diferente que no coincida con la siguiente compilación.

Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Te faltaría indicar si esa identificación debe ser única por maquina y/o por versión de la aplicación, que uso pretendes darle, etc. Qt tiene mecanismos para gestionar identificadores únicos, pero a falta de una mejor explicación...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yo compilo un programa cada vez que compilo ese programa tiene que tener un ALIAS diferente que no coincida con la siguiente compilación.

Podrías usar las macros predefinidas de `__DATE__` y `__TIME__`, de esta manera cada vez tendrás un valor diferente a no ser que viajes al pasado o cambies la fecha de tu sistema:

```
constexpr std::string ALIAS("Mi programa " __DATE__ " " __TIME__);
std::cout << "El alias del programa es: " << ALIAS;
```

El código anterior podría imprimir el siguiente mensaje:

> ```
> El alias del programa es: Mi programa Oct 26 1985 22:29:34
> ```

Comment: buena idea no creo que dos personas ejecuten el programa en la misma hora y dia? xD

Comment: @OmarAlami ¿Te refieres a que dos personas compilen el programa el mismo día y hora? Esa constante de concatenar fecha y hora se genera en el momento de **compilar**... así que cabe la posibilidad de que suceda, pero a no ser que se pongan de acuerdo es poco probable.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que sí. Abres el fichero en modo binario y vuelcas todo el contenido en una cadena. Por ejemplo, a través de un `std::ostringstream`. Imagina un programa que se hashea a sí mismo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input(argv[0], std::ios::binary);
    std::ostringstream output;

    output << input.rdbuf();

    std::cout << tu_funcion_de_hasheo(output.str()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Has ido a elegir una de las formas más lentas de leer un fichero jejejeje. Te lo comento porque justamente acabo de responder en este otro hilo y lo mismo te interesa: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28365/es-recomendable-cargar-todo-un-archivo-de-texto-a-un-string

Comment: Gracias por el apunte.