# Como eliminar los "residuos" de un stringstream?

Tags: c++

Al intentar resolver esta [problema](http://www.minidosis.org/#/actividades/Cpp.StringStreams.Mayores.prob) con esta [respuesta](http://cpp.sh/7iw3y) me encontre con el problema de que no puedo eliminar los "residuos" que quedan después de usar `stringstream` y quería preguntarles si me pueden aconsejar en como eliminar la basura que queda.

El residuo que me queda es el `-1.23` de la segunda linea el cual molesta, ya que la tercera linea no contiene nada y se carga el ultimo dato que es el `-1.23`

> **Nota:** Estoy usando el compilador llamado Code::Blocks, version: 16.01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema está en la condición del `while` interno. Cuando se lee el último número de una línea, por ejemplo, tu `-1.23`, el flujo se para justo detrás del `-1.23`, sin llegar a encontrar `eof`, y por tanto, `!ss.eof() == true`, entrando en el bucle de nuevo.

Y con la línea vacía igual: si aún no has empezado a leer `!ss.eof() == true`, y al entrar, `i == 1`.

¿Por qué `b` sigue valiendo `1.23`? Porque al entrar en el bucle aunque no haya datos, `ss >> b` falla (aquí es cuando encuentra `eof`), y `b` no se modifica.

La solución es sustituir el bucle interno de:

```
while(!ss.eof())
```

por

```
while (ss >> b)
```

En decir, lo que te interesa es saber si la lectura `ss >> b` se ha podido completar. De todas formas, tienes más errores (`a` debería ser `float` y podría haber números menores a `-10000`), además del hecho de que los `double`s sean normalmente más eficientes que los `float`s [†].

Aquí la versión mejorada:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("mayores.txt");
    string in;

    while(getline(f, in)) { // Misma razón que con `ss`.
       int i = 0, j;
       double a = std::numeric_limits<double>::min(), b;

       istringstream ss(in);

       while(ss >> b){
            ++i; // <pedantic_mode>: ++i es más eficiente que i++.

            if(b > a){
                a = b;
                j = i;
            }
        }

        if(i == 0) j = -1;

        cout << j << endl;
    }
}
```

O, versión corta (aunque no más eficiente), con iteradores, que me encantan:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("mayores.txt");
    string in;
    vector<double> line_values; // [†2]

    while(getline(f, in)) {
       line_values.clear();
       istringstream ss(in);

       copy(istream_iterator<double>(ss), istream_iterator<double>(),
            back_inserter(line_values));

       auto it = max_element(line_values.begin(), line_values.end());
       cout << distance(line_values.begin(), it) - 1 << endl; // [†3]
    }
}
```

**[†]:** La eficiencia `float` vs. `double` depende de la arquitectura. Si la unidad de punto flotante del procesador está implementada para tratar con `float`s, los `double`s son más lentos porque hay que ir transformando los valores devueltos por el procesador (`float`) al tipo de destino (`double`). Y viceversa. Pues resulta que la mayoría de procesadores modernos trabajan nativamente con `double`s.

**[†2]:** Los vectores reservan memoria a medida que crecen, y `clear()` no libera la memoria previamente reservada, para no tener que volverla a reservar. Es decir, que la memoria reservada actualmente por el vector (`capacity()`) es siempre mayor o igual que su tamaño actual (`size()`). Por eso declaro el `vector` fuera del bucle, para aprovechar la `capacity()` adquirida en vueltas anteriores del bucle.

**[†3]:** `max_element()` devuelve un iterador al mayor elemento. Si el vector está vacío, `max_element(v.begin(), v.end()) == v.end()`, y `std::distance` devolverá 0.

**NOTA:** Para el curioso, aquí una versión con iteradores que solo recorre la secuencia de valores una vez:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using double_reader = std::istream_iterator<double>;

int main()
{
    istringstream f("mayores.txt");
    string in;

    while(getline(f, in)) {
        istringstream ss(in);

        int pos = -1, max_pos = -1;
        double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();

        for_each(double_reader(ss), double_reader(), [&](const double& d) {
            ++pos;

            if (d > max) {
                max = d;
                max_pos = pos;
            }
        });

       cout << max_pos << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta :) me sorprende que [bassily](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6489/bassily) se enfrente al problema del uso incorrecto de `stream::eof` en un bucle cuando en otra pregunta [se le aconsejó no usarlo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28452/2742) :O

Comment: @Peregring-lk si es menos eficiente, ¿por que usas iteradores?

Comment: @bassily Los iteradores no son menos eficientes per sé. Ese código es menos eficiente porque utilizo un vector auxiliar, para que `std::distance` sea una operación no lineal. Lo puse solo como ilustración por ser mucho más legible que una versión iterativa. No sería difícil crear un iterador de salida que vaya acumulando el máximo valor, y así recorrer el flujo solo una vez.

Comment: @Peregring-lk lo **siento**, lei mal la linea de "...O, versión corta (aunque no más eficiente), con iteradores, que me encantan:..."

Comment: @bassily Ya que estamos, he añadido una versión con iteradores que no es más ineficiente que con un bucle, pero utilizando lambdas.